Как вызывать множество слайдеров не через new?
Есть много слайдеров до после , нужно сделать так, чтобы они вызывались не через
new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#one'
}); 
new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#two'
});
new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#two'
});

А как-то общим, заранее спасибо
Вот код


class BeforeAfter {
  constructor(enteryObject) {

      const beforeAfterContainer = document.querySelector(enteryObject.id);
      const before = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before');
      const beforeText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-beforePosition');
      const afterText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-afterPosition');
      const handle = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-handle');
      var widthChange = 0;

      beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
      window.onresize = function () {
          beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
      }
      before.setAttribute('style', "width: 50%;");
      handle.setAttribute('style', "left: 50%;");

      //touch screen event listener
      beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {

          beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchmove", (e2) => {
              let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
              let currentPoint = e2.changedTouches[0].clientX;

              let startOfDiv = beforeAfterContainer.offsetLeft;

              let modifiedCurrentPoint = currentPoint - startOfDiv;

              if (modifiedCurrentPoint > 10 && modifiedCurrentPoint < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
                  let newWidth = modifiedCurrentPoint * 100 / containerWidth;

                  before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
                  afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index: 1;");
                  handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
              }
          });
      });

      //mouse move event listener
      beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
          let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
          widthChange = e.offsetX;
          let newWidth = widthChange * 100 / containerWidth;

          if (e.offsetX > 10 && e.offsetX < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
              before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
              afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index:" + "1;");
              handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
          }
      })

  }
}

new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#one'
});
new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#two'
});
new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#two'
});
.bal-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: grab;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.bal-after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* right: 0; */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before-inset {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.bal-after img,
.bal-before img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bal-beforePosition {
    background: #121212;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.bal-afterPosition {
    background: #121212;
    color: #fff;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.beforeLabel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.afterLabel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


/* handle and arrow */

.bal-handle {
    height: 41px;
    width: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -21px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    z-index: 20;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.handle-left-arrow,
.handle-right-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px inset transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.handle-left-arrow {
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
}

.handle-right-arrow {
    border-left: 6px solid #fff;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -17px;
}

.bal-handle::before {
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::after {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 20.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::before,
.bal-handle::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 9999px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}
    <div class="mainSection">
    
        <div id="one" class="bal-container">
            <div class="bal-after">
                <img src="https://img1.fonwall.ru/o/qc/animal-pet-cat-mammal.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;fit=resize&amp;w=1200&amp;display=large">
                <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
                    After
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="bal-before">
                <div class="bal-before-inset">
                    <img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/5/18/289291145046987/evropejskaya-koshka-dikij-kot-morda-vzglyad.jpg">
                    <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
                        Before
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="bal-handle">
                <span class=" handle-left-arrow"></span>
                <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div id="two" class="bal-container">
            <div class="bal-after">
                <img src="https://img1.fonwall.ru/o/qc/animal-pet-cat-mammal.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;fit=resize&amp;w=1200&amp;display=large">
                <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
                    After
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bal-before">
                <div class="bal-before-inset">
                    <img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/5/18/289291145046987/evropejskaya-koshka-dikij-kot-morda-vzglyad.jpg">
                    <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
                        Before
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bal-handle">
                <span class="handle-left-arrow"></span>
                <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="three" class="bal-container">
            <div class="bal-after">
                <img src="https://img1.fonwall.ru/o/qc/animal-pet-cat-mammal.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;fit=resize&amp;w=1200&amp;display=large">
                <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
                    After
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bal-before">
                <div class="bal-before-inset">
                    <img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/5/18/289291145046987/evropejskaya-koshka-dikij-kot-morda-vzglyad.jpg">
                    <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
                        Before
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bal-handle">
                <span class="handle-left-arrow"></span>
                <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




А как-то общим - это как к примеру? чем вам текущая реализация не нравится, что с ней так?

Будет не известное количетсво слайдеров. И нужно сделать так, чтобы они вызывались какой-то одной функцие

Создайте функцию, в которой отбераете querySelectoAll элементы по нужному селектору и далее в цикле по полученной коллекции выполняете инициализацию слайдера. Однако, вам надо смотреть на html разметку аккуратно и при создании новых элементов указывать уникальный id, т.к. слайдер ищет элемент при помощи querySelector, а он будет искать до первого найденного, а если ничего не найдет, то сломается.

Могли бы написать код? Была бы очень благодарна вам

Если нужно ставить слайдер неизвестное количество раз, то как вариант:
Выбрать все элементы с классом bal-container и для каждого элемента вызвать установщик слайдера, передав ему id текущего элемента
function run() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.bal-container').forEach(el => {
      new BeforeAfter({
        id: `#${el.id}`
      })
    })
  }
run();


Вызывает ошибку

Нужно написать: '#' + el.id

@ΝNL993 точно, поправил

@Майя поправил селектор

Спасибо, все работает

вот только у элемента с классом может вообще не быть id. Лучше передавать сам элемент в конструктор, раз уже его все равно уже нашли
